# passing an class object through intent to broadcast receiver in android

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

Hi all I am got stuck in a point , please help me out.

In my service

```
ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage();
chatMessage.setId(10)
chatMessage.setMessage("hello");
Intent intent = new Intent("MessageReceiver");
intent.putExtra("chatobj", chatMessage);
getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

in  my Activity

```
public final BroadcastReceiver ReceiveChat = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(getIntent().getSerializableExtra("chatobj"));
Log.v(CommonUtilities.TAG, chatMessage.getMessage()+": new message");
}};
```

This code is at my start of the activity , before oncreate(). Is this a problem ?
The Log has null value. why is that ?

Comment: Please Write ChatMessage implements Serializable in model class.Issue will be resolved

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Implements `Serializable` in model class. Issue will be resolved**

Like this

```
public class ChatMessage  implements Serializable{

 int id; 
 String name;
}
```

**send data like this**

```
Intent intent = new Intent("MessageReceiver");
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putSerializable("chatobj",(Serializable)chatobj);
intent.putExtra("DATA",args);
startActivity(intent);
```

**receive data like this**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle args = intent.getBundleExtra("DATA");
ChatMessage chatMessage = (ChatMessage) args.getSerializable("chatobj");
```

Comment: i have done it already,  even i have 3 constructors in that class.  public ChatMessage(){}

    public ChatMessage(Serializable chatmsg){    }

Answer (score 0):

In `onReceive()` you do this:

```
ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(getIntent().getSerializableExtra("chatobj"));
```

This tries to get the "chatobj" extra from the `Intent` that the `Activity` was started with (`getIntent()` is a method on `Activity`, not a method on `BroadcastReceiver`), and this is why you get `null`.

You need to use the `Intent` that was passed to `onReceive()`:

```
ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(intent.getSerializableExtra("chatobj"));
```

Comment: Sorry Sir , still it is null.